# How do I specify a DVD's title and chapter on the vlc command line?

Tags: vlc

I have an ISO file ripped from cinema DVD with menus.
I want to know how to play the ripped movie ISO file with VLC.app from main contents not from menu.
According to help manual, when I start to play VLC from certain chapter, I can use command line like below.

```
vlc dvd://[device][@raw_device][@[title][:[chapter][:angle]]]
```

Such that, I tried below. But error occured.

```
vlc /Path_to_file/Platoon.ISO ://@1:2

vlc /Path_to_file/Platoon.ISO
```

Actually this latter simple command worked, but the title menu begins which I didn't want.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues there. Firstly, the man page actually specifies:

```
dvd://[<device>][@<raw device>][#[<title>][:[<chapter>][:<angle>]]]
```

ie. title/chapter specification is separated by a `#`, not `@`.

Secondly, this is all one argument, without spaces. So, for your case (using title 1, chapter 2), you would want something like:

```
vlc dvd:///path/to/dvd.iso#1:2
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Have to agree with OP:  From [the manual](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Opening_a_DVD_or_VCD.2C_or_an_audio_CD): "vlc dvd://[device][@raw_device][@[title][:[chapter][:angle]]]"

Comment: This solved my problem too (using openSUSE/KDE). To be fair, on a Windows command line, the @ character works